# Insert Page Break at specified line number Word with vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to build a report from vb.net, and here is

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim oTable As Word.Table

    For Each dc As BSPLib.Bills.BillDeliverychallan In Bill.BillDCs

        Dim dcpara As Word.Paragraph
        dcpara = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range)
        dcpara.Range.Font.Bold = 5
        dcpara.Range.Text = "Delivery Challan: " & dc.DCName
        dcpara.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
        dcpara.Format.SpaceBefore = 12
        dcpara.Format.SpaceAfter = 2   '24 pt spacing after paragraph.
        dcpara.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

        Dim count As Integer = dc.BillItems.Count

        Dim r As Integer
        oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, count + 1, 7)
        oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 2
        oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        oTable.Columns(1).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(0.89)
        oTable.Columns(2).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(5.58)
        oTable.Columns(3).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(2)
        oTable.Columns(4).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(0.6)
        oTable.Columns(5).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(1.7)
        oTable.Columns(6).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
        oTable.Columns(7).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(2.01)
        For r = 1 To count
            'BQT TABLES 15  NOS @   25.00   =   375.00
            oTable.Cell(r, 1).Range.Text = dc.BillItems(r - 1).ItemSerial & "."
            oTable.Cell(r, 1).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
            oTable.Cell(r, 1).Range.Font.Bold = 0
            oTable.Cell(r, 2).Range.Text = dc.BillItems(r - 1).ItemName
            oTable.Cell(r, 2).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft
            oTable.Cell(r, 2).Range.Font.Bold = 0
            oTable.Cell(r, 3).Range.Text = dc.BillItems(r - 1).Quantity & " " & dc.BillItems(r - 1).ItemMeasure
            oTable.Cell(r, 3).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
            oTable.Cell(r, 3).Range.Font.Bold = 0

            oTable.Cell(r, 4).Range.Text = "@"
            oTable.Cell(r, 4).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
            oTable.Cell(r, 4).Range.Font.Bold = 0
            oTable.Cell(r, 5).Range.Text = dc.BillItems(r - 1).PricePerUnit.ToString("F")
            oTable.Cell(r, 5).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
            oTable.Cell(r, 5).Range.Font.Bold = 0
            oTable.Cell(r, 6).Range.Text = "="
            oTable.Cell(r, 6).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
            oTable.Cell(r, 6).Range.Font.Bold = 0
            oTable.Cell(r, 7).Range.Text = dc.BillItems(r - 1).TotalFinal.ToString("F")
            oTable.Cell(r, 7).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
            oTable.Cell(r, 7).Range.Font.Bold = 0
        Next
        oTable.Cell(r + 1, 7).Range.Text = (dc.Total / dc.Days).ToString("F")
        oTable.Cell(r + 1, 7).Range.Font.Bold = 0
        oTable.Cell(r, 7).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
        oTable.Rows.Alignment = Word.WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowLeft

        'Using a line break before my next table
        Dim oLineBreak1 As Word.Paragraph
        oLineBreak1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range)
        oLineBreak1.Format.SpaceAfter = 0
        oLineBreak1.Format.SpaceBefore = 0
        oLineBreak1.Range.Font.Size = 2

        oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 1, 2)
        oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        If dc.Days > 1 Then
            oTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "    From " & dc.FromDate.ToShortDateString & " To " & dc.ToDate & " --- " & dc.Days & " days" & " For: " & dc.ForDate
        Else
            oTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "    From " & dc.FromDate.ToShortDateString & " To " & dc.ToDate & " --- " & dc.Days & " day" & " For:" & dc.ForDate
        End If
        oTable.Cell(1, 1).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(12.44)
        oTable.Cell(1, 2).Width = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(2.67)
        oTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = dc.Total.ToString("F")
        oTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight
        oTable.Rows.Alignment = Word.WdRowAlignment.wdAlignRowCenter




        'Dim break As Word.WdBreakType
        'End If
    Next
```

The problem is, if the data in the for each loop extends to next page, I want the entire data in for loop to move to next page.  I think of adding a page count integer and verify it with starting and ending to determine and change the page.  The problem is I dont know how to insert a page break at a specified line number.  page break is `Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak` but how to insert it at a line number?

Thank you.

Comment: In simple, what my question is: I want to inset before dcpara but program code inserted at end of the loop before 'Next'.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you just format the pargraph "keep together".

Comment: @Blam, how can I do that, can you give some more information it.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I don't know how in automation but I know if I am doing it Word directly that is how I keep a paragraph to together.  And there is a together with next that you many needs to use.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for in automation.

Comment: And you don't think you can apply formatting to a paragraph in automation?  In your code sample I see .Format.  Show some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the paragraph as "**Keep Together**":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.keeptogether.aspx

> Determines if all lines in the specified paragraphs remain on the same page when Microsoft Word repaginates the document.

This ensures that individual lines of a paragraph don't get separated across two pages.

You will also want to use "**Keep with Next**":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.keepwithnext.aspx

> Determines if the specified paragraph remains on the same page as the paragraph that follows it when Microsoft Word repaginates the document.

This ensures that individual paragraphs aren't separated from each other across two pages.

Comment: @alain Your edit deleted one of the links.   That was two separate links and both may be required for the problem.

Comment: My mistake. In any event, I understand that you're frustrated with the lack of effort on the part of the asker, but I still want the solution to contain a little more information than just two links.

Comment: Also note that your most recent edit has both links pointing to the "KeepWithNext" page. Probably just a copy/paste error.

Comment: @alien I want to get it right and I appreciated your edits.  Did you fix it because right now it is pointing at two different pages when I click them.

Comment: Yep, it's all fixed up now. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for me not being able to reply, I was forced to go out of town.  To the answer, In this case, it is not just one para, the for loop has  2 paras and 2 tables, in this case how can I do it?  Thanks for your time and patience shown.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you think "Keep with Next" means.  Show some effort.

Comment: I tried with keeping the Keep with Next as true for the DC para and the results were that everything went to next page starting from it although they are in different loop.  For Keep together I tried it this way, dcpara.keeptogether=olinebreak1.keeptogether and I saw no difference, even the msdn could had given some small example would been better for starters like me.  Could you please guide me where I have gone wrong.  Thank you for your time and patience in this matter.